# Assistance Request for Stripe Payment Gateway Automation Issue in Cypress script with JS

Tags: automation, stripe-payments, ui-automation

I am currently facing an issue with automating Stripe payment gateway using Cypress. Despite manually identifying the Stripe iframe body, it does not appear during the script execution, preventing successful automation.
Cypress ver: 13.3.2
OS - Linux

I am currently facing an issue with automating Stripe payment gateway using Cypress. Despite manually identifying the Stripe iframe body, it does not appear during the script execution, preventing successful automation.

Comment: Stripe recommends against Automated e2e tests. You can read more about it [here](https://stripe.com/docs/automated-testing)